# Рисовать курсором мыши на поле QGraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpainter, qgraphicsview

Мне нужно сделать поле для рисования.

Во время того, как кнопка мыши зажимается или просто нажимается, нужно рисовать на месте, где находится курсор точку.

Цвет точки и цвет листа выбираются при нажатии кнопок `brushColorBtn` и `backgrColorBtn` соответственно.

Также желательно бы сделать возможность изменять размер точки.

**main.py**:

```
class Form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('drawcreator.ui', self)
        self.brushColor = 'black'
        self.backgrColor = 'white'
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.brushColorBtn.setToolTip('Открыть QColorDialog')
        self.brushColorBtn.clicked.connect(self.getBrushColor)
        self.backgrColorBtn.setToolTip('Открыть QColorDialog')
        self.backgrColorBtn.clicked.connect(self.getBackgrColor)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawPoint(qp)
        qp.end()

    def getBrushColor(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            self.brushColor = color

    def getBackgrColor(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            self.backgrColor = color

    def drawPoint(self,qp):
        width = self.brushWidthSBox.text()
        qp.setBrush(self.brushColor)
        # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**drawcreator.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_forthForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, forthForm):
        forthForm.setObjectName("forthForm")
        forthForm.resize(771, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(forthForm)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.drawWindow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.drawWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 70, 601, 451))
        self.drawWindow.setObjectName("drawWindow")
        self.brushWidthSBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.brushWidthSBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans Condensed")
        self.brushWidthSBox.setFont(font)
        self.brushWidthSBox.setMinimum(4)
        self.brushWidthSBox.setObjectName("brushWidthSBox")
        self.savePicBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.savePicBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 530, 101, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.savePicBtn.setFont(font)
        self.savePicBtn.setObjectName("savePicBtn")
        self.brushWidthLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.brushWidthLbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 101, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.brushWidthLbl.setFont(font)
        self.brushWidthLbl.setObjectName("brushWidthLbl")
        self.createArtLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.createArtLbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 20, 601, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.createArtLbl.setFont(font)
        self.createArtLbl.setObjectName("createArtLbl")
        self.pic3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pic3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 420, 131, 131))
        self.pic3.setText("")
        self.pic3.setObjectName("pic3")
        self.brushColorBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.brushColorBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        self.brushColorBtn.setFont(font)
        self.brushColorBtn.setObjectName("brushColorBtn")
        self.backgrColorBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backgrColorBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        self.backgrColorBtn.setFont(font)
        self.backgrColorBtn.setObjectName("backgrColorBtn")
        forthForm.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(forthForm)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 771, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        forthForm.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(forthForm)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        forthForm.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(forthForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(forthForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, forthForm):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        forthForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("forthForm", "MainWindow"))
        self.savePicBtn.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Сохранить"))
        self.brushWidthLbl.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Ширина кисти:"))
        self.createArtLbl.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Создайте рисунок"))
        self.brushColorBtn.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Цвет кисти"))
        self.backgrColorBtn.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Цвет фона"))
```

Comment: Вы что-то подобное хотели: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7ec432aa45b0fb87f62361f108eebeab38184393/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__QGraphicsScene__draw_selection_rect.py#L14?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/223536).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я практический выполнил все ваши желания, но виджет `QGraphicsView` был изменен на `QLabel`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor('#0000ff')
        self.pen_width = 4
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)            

    def set_pen_color(self, c):
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor(c)

    def set_pen_width(self, n):
        self.pen_width = n

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_x is None: # Первое событие
            self.last_x = e.x()
            self.last_y = e.y()
            return              # Игнорировать в первый раз.

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p = painter.pen()
        p.setWidth(self.pen_width)
        p.setColor(self.pen_color)
        painter.setPen(p)
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y+75, e.x(), e.y()+75)
        painter.end()
        self.update()

        # Обновите источник 
        self.last_x = e.x()
        self.last_y = e.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.last_x = None
        self.last_y = None


class Ui_forthForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, forthForm):
        forthForm.setObjectName("forthForm")
        forthForm.resize(771, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(forthForm)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

#        self.drawWindow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.drawWindow = Label(self.centralwidget)                        # Label !!!

        self.drawWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 70, 601, 451))
        self.drawWindow.setObjectName("drawWindow")

        self.brushWidthSBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.brushWidthSBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans Condensed")
        self.brushWidthSBox.setFont(font)
#        self.brushWidthSBox.setMinimum(4)                                 
        self.brushWidthSBox.setRange(1, 10)

        self.brushWidthSBox.setObjectName("brushWidthSBox")

        self.savePicBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.savePicBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 530, 101, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.savePicBtn.setFont(font)
        self.savePicBtn.setObjectName("savePicBtn")

        self.brushWidthLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.brushWidthLbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 101, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.brushWidthLbl.setFont(font)
        self.brushWidthLbl.setObjectName("brushWidthLbl")

        self.createArtLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)      # Создайте рисунок
        self.createArtLbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 20, 601, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.createArtLbl.setFont(font)
        self.createArtLbl.setObjectName("createArtLbl")

        self.pic3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pic3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 420, 131, 131))
        self.pic3.setText("")
        self.pic3.setObjectName("pic3")

        self.brushColorBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.brushColorBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        self.brushColorBtn.setFont(font)
        self.brushColorBtn.setObjectName("brushColorBtn")

        self.backgrColorBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)  # Цвет фона
        self.backgrColorBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Courier")
        self.backgrColorBtn.setFont(font)
        self.backgrColorBtn.setObjectName("backgrColorBtn")

        forthForm.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(forthForm)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 771, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        forthForm.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(forthForm)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        forthForm.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(forthForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(forthForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, forthForm):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        forthForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("forthForm", "MainWindow"))
        self.savePicBtn.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Сохранить"))
        self.brushWidthLbl.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Ширина кисти:"))
        self.createArtLbl.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Создайте рисунок"))
        self.brushColorBtn.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Цвет кисти"))
        self.backgrColorBtn.setText(_translate("forthForm", "Цвет фона"))



class Form(QMainWindow, Ui_forthForm):  # + Ui_forthForm
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

#        uic.loadUi('drawcreator.ui', self)
        self.setupUi(self)                                          # +++

        self.initUI()

        canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(600, 600)
        self.drawWindow.setPixmap(canvas)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(600, 600)

        self.backgrColor = QtCore.Qt.black
        self.pixmap.fill(self.backgrColor)


        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 85))
        qp.drawEllipse(140, 100, 120, 120)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0, 85))
        qp.drawEllipse(100, 180, 120, 120)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255, 85))
        qp.drawEllipse(180, 180, 120, 120)
        qp.end()
        self.drawWindow.setPixmap(self.pixmap)        


    def initUI(self):
        self.brushColorBtn.setToolTip('Открыть QColorDialog')
        self.brushColorBtn.clicked.connect(self.getBrushColor)    
        self.brushWidthSBox.valueChanged.connect(self.qspinbox_value_changed)   # +++
        self.backgrColorBtn.setToolTip('Открыть QColorDialog')
        self.backgrColorBtn.clicked.connect(self.getBackgrColor)   

    def qspinbox_value_changed(self, new_value):          # pen Width
        self.drawWindow.set_pen_width(new_value)        

    def getBrushColor(self):                              # Цвет кисти
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            self.drawWindow.set_pen_color(color)

    def getBackgrColor(self):                             # Цвет фона
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            print(color)
            self.pixmap.fill(color)
            self.drawWindow.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]